# Sync frame playback of video in opencv by timestamps

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm running a video processing alg (python opencv) and would like to compare the frame-by-frame analysis to a similar commercial alg. I have a csv file generated from the similar alg that has timestamps with the corresponding output for the entire video. The csv file is in form shown below. With a timestamp and TRUE/FALSE (1/0).

```
| Time             | Output|  
|------------------|--------|  
| 00:01:10.345     | 1 |
```

The video is a 30fps .avi file. I'm having issues getting the frames between the two algs to line up so I can compare the outputs. Here's what I've tried so far.

### Idea 1

I tried to playback the video by setting the timestamp to be from the csv file before reading every frame. Every timestamp in the csv is 33ms apart (confirmed through calculation). It is recorded at 30fps so it should have one timestamp per frame.

The timestamps are in the form hh:mm:ss.000 as shown above.  Here's my code to set the time:

```
def setByTime():
    cap.set(0,timeToMilli(csv['Time'][index]))
def timeToMilli(s):
    s = s.replace(".",":")
    hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds = s.split(":")
    return int(hours)*60*60*1000 + int(minutes)*60*1000 + int(seconds)*1000 + int(milliseconds)
```

However this doesn't playback the video correctly. I can play it side by side with the same video open in VLC and the timestamps compared to the frame are not the correct. Opencv will play very slowly, until it hits a breaking point of sorts where it'll skip a few frames and then play really quickly for a few frames and catch up to the normal video in VLC. This way seems very inefficient, but would ensure that the frames line up if it worked.

## Idea 2

Because the video and the csv timestamps are 30fps I figured I could playback the video normally and increment my csv index every frame to get the corresponding output. However, when those timestamps are compared opencv slowly outpaces the csv and by the end of the video is minutes ahead.

```
# This changes over time!! About 1 milliscond every 3 frames
diff = timeToMilli(csv['Time'][index]) - cap.get(0)

# Returns 30 as expected
fps = cap.get(5)
```

Playing the video this way, it is also visually faster than watching the video in VLC.

### Question

Any ideas of syncing playback of a video to timestamps in python opencv? Is opencv running faster than 30fps? Or is it possibly some sort of encoding issue.

Comment: Hi SchatzaM, did you get any answer for this question? Please let me know